# Transform shapefile in UTM-Zone32N to UTM-Zone33N in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm using corine data, which I have downloaded for Germany with the following KBS: EPSG:32633 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N - Projiziert

https://land.copernicus.eu/pan-european/corine-land-cover

Now I want to transform it to UTM Zone 33N, not 32. But If I set it to 33N, and save it, it still doesn't fit wit my other 33N layers.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You say you "set it to 33N". How did you do this? Did you right click in the legend and "Set Layer CRS"? If so, you are just telling the system the current data is in that CRS, which is not true. You need to right click and export the features as a new layer, setting the desired CRS in the export dialog. This will actually transform the data.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure that the original Corine data are projected in:

European Terrestrial Reference System 1989 (ETRS89) datum and
Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area (LAEA) projection (EPSG: 3035).  Not UTM.